# Azure VM scale set in existing resource group

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine, azure-vm-scale-set

Is there a way to create a VM Scaleset in an existing Azure Resource Group?
Currently the portal does not show that as an option, is it possible through powershell?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, when we create VMSS via Azure poratl, we can't choose an existing Azure resource group, you can use PowerShell to create a VMSS in an existing Azure group, more information about how to use PowerShell to create VMSS, refer to the [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/virtual-machines-windows-vmss-powershell-creating).
In the example, we can use `$rgname = "myresourcegroupname"`, about `New-AzureRmResourceGroup -Name $rgname -Location $loc` is optional.